# Calling a constructor for an object more than once

Tags: c++, oop

This code works fine. Instead of calling a setter function I used constructor and I am calling constructor for an object multiple times. Isn't constructor called only once for one object? Is it right or wrong to do as I did?

```
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("phones.txt");
    DirectoryEntry *TelephoneDirectory = new DirectoryEntry[size]; // default constructor
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        TelephoneDirectory[i] = DirectoryEntry(myfile); // parameterized constructor
    }
    myfile.close();
```

Comment: How else would you create multiple instances of some class?? Each call would create a _new_ object.

Comment: "and I am calling constructor for an object multiple times." You aren't, those are different objects.

Comment: `TelephoneDirectory[i] = DirectoryEntry(myfile);` - constructs a temporary`DirectoryEntry`; then assigns (copies) it into the array element; then destroys the temporary.

Comment: maybe it will help you if you take a look at how assignment operator/ copy constructor are implemented

Comment: @ForceBru couldn't a setter function have worked?

Comment: @tobi303 what do you mean, I didn't understand what does assignment operator have to do with this?

Comment: @Goodfellow, your current approach works as well. A setter function will also work.

Answer (score 2):

> Instead of calling a setter function I used constructor and I am calling constructor for an object multiple times.

No you are not calling constructor multiple times. You code is pretty much similar to:

```
DirectoryEntry object;
object = DirectoryEntry( myfile );
```

you create `object`, invoking default ctor then create temporary and assign it to `object`. There are no multiple calls of ctor for `object`. So your code is completely valid (assuming ctors and assignment operator are valid), but if it does what you really wanted depends, as you do not seem to understand what is going on here.

Comment: Thanks.
I was pretty sure when I wrote it, but then my instructor told me that "why is a constructor being called for multiple times, it shouldn't work.."
And then I was confused...

Comment: You may consider to change instructor as he/she seems to not understand basics of the language.

Comment: That is not up to me!
Maybe he was just trying to confuse me while evaluating the code?

Comment: @Goodfellow I doubt that would be a good way to educate, you suppose to trust what your instructor tells you. Unless instructor formulate this as a question but not as a statement.